# Which is the equivalent in Mongoose of this MongoDb query db.collection.find( { tags: { $all: [some elements in the array] } } )

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to find an equivalent to this MongoDB query `db.inventory.find( { tags: { $all: ["red", "blank"]}})` in Mongoose. I found this one in Mongoose `Model.find({'field': { $in: array name })` but it gives me as results documents with all elements in the array in a document and also documents that matches at least one of the elements in the array.

Here is a code I am using to display artisans with specific specialties:

**display artisans profiles route**

```
app.post('/artisanprofile', function(req, res){
  const profile = [];
  const result = req.body.search;
  console.log(result);
  console.log(typeof result);
  const specialities = result.split(" ");
  console.log(specialities);
  Artisan.find({
    'speciality': { $in: specialities }
}, function(err, profiles) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log(profiles);
  }
});
});
```

the documents I am looking for are ones with specialties test and test1 but I get all documents with at least one of the elements in the array `specialties` passed to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it
use and and for each element of `specialities` use $in

```
app.post('/artisanprofile', function(req, res){
  const profile = [];
  const result = req.body.search;
  console.log(result);
  console.log(typeof result);
  const specialities = result.split(" ");
  console.log(specialities);
  var andObj = {}
  var andArr = []
  specialities.forEach(item=>{
      var itemArr = []
      itemArr.push(item)
      andObj['$in'] :itemArr
      andArr.push({speciality:andObj})
      andObj = {}
  })
  Artisan.find({
    $and : andArr
}, function(err, profiles) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log(profiles);
  }
});
});
```